# Vertical-oriented bootstrap-slider reverses value

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap-slider (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/) with vertical orientation. When I move slider up, it decrease value, but it should increase it. Is it a bug or I missed some setting?

```
<input type="text" class="sliderMaster slider-horizontal" id="sl1" name="q12" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="50" data-slider-orientation="vertical" data-slider-selection="none" data-slider-tooltip="show">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marboni/B7Jym/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug, or that there are settings to easily do so. But, so far, I found 2 methods to achieve such behavior.

first is to trick the slider to the max value of 0 and the min value of 100 [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scLGV/1/), but than the initial value does not work and I dont figure out how to get it working again.

JS

```
$(function(){    
    $('#sl1').slider({
        max: 0.0,
          formater: function(value) {
            return 'Current value: '+value;
          }
    });
});
```

and the other is not to show the actual value, but  max value minus the actual value [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qDpy6/1/). 
pro: the initial value is working again,
 contra: you have to remember this every time you retrieve the value of the slider.

JS

```
$(function(){    
    $('#sl1').slider({
          formater: function(value) {
            return 'Current value: '+(this.max -value);
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: I preferred second solution because of initial value. Your method works good for ranges started from 0. In my case I'd like to set scale, so there is no sense to make it 0. I made min value 0.1 and max value 1.9 (to place 1 at the middle), calculating actual one subtracting slider's value from 2.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is very simple : set the "reversed" option to true, and the value will increase when you move the slider up.

```
$('#sl1').slider({
      formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: '+value;
      },
      reversed: true
});
```

Note that you need to upgrade your version of the library for "reversed" to be taken into acccount.

See updated fiddle for demonstration with the current github version : http://jsfiddle.net/Lp9HL/